# Limit of integral to integral of limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Given $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ measurable and $f:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ measurable and positive then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\int_E (f(x))^{\frac{1}{n}} dx} = m(E)$

I feel like id need to apply the dominated convergen theorem to solve this but i can't find an integrable function $g$ such that $|f_n|\leq g$.

I'd apreciate some tips on how to find the integrable function for this kind of problems as I'm new to this theores and I'm not used to working with them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider $f_n=f^{\frac{1}{n}}$. Then $|f_n|\leq \max{(1,|f|)}$ and $\{f_n\}_n$ converges poitnwise to the identically $1$ function. Dominated convergence gives you the result then. You can be even a bit more precise, as what i write here works if $f$ is integrable. Otherwise you can just take the identically $2$ function for $n$ large enough.

Comment: So you are suggesting to use $|f|$ as the integrable function greater than all $f_n$ in the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: In that case, doesn't $f$ have to be integrable?

Comment: Yeah sorry, realized that after posting. Fixed in the meanwhile.

Comment: And what if the measure of E is infinity? then the identically 2 function isn't integrable right?

Comment: Well neither is the identically $1$ function. But then you only need to show that the limit on the LHS is infinite and this is trivial as for example $f_n>\frac{1}{2}$ for $n$ large enough. I am assuming that you meant $f$ is strictly positive btw, otherwise the statement would definitely be wrong (e.g. if $f$ is identically $0$).

Comment: Also, doesn't the function $g$ that bounds all $f_n$ have to be greater or equal $|f_n|$ for all n not just after a certain point?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what taking the limit means. I can start defining the $f_n$ from an arbitrary point, i.e. I can set $f_n=f^{\frac{1}{N+n}}$ for an arbitrary natural $N$. Also you asked for a hint, not for a full solution. You obviously have to treat some special cases separately, like if $f$ is not strictly positive or if $m(E)=\infty$ or if $f$ is unbounded from above.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $m(E)<\infty$ and $f^{1/n}$ is integrable on $E$ for some $n$, then one can use the dominated convergence theorem. But without an inregrability assumption, the conclusion can fail, consider $f(x)=e^{1/x}$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: The conclusion for infinite measure sets is true by Fatou's Lemma.